# Wpf control transformation

Tags: c#, wpf, transformation

I am trying to move a border to an other canvas from a rotated canvas but the border do not have the same position after paste. There are 2 borders in the code to see the old border position. How do I make the border to stay in the same position after paste?

```xml
<Grid>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas1" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="100" Width="300" Height="250" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="Gray" Opacity="0.1">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Border x:Name="brd1" Canvas.Left="80" Background="Black" Width="100" Height="200" CornerRadius="30,0,10,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.29,0.862">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="47.958"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="brd2" Canvas.Left="80" Background="Black" Width="100" Height="200" CornerRadius="30,0,10,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.29,0.862">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="47.958"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">

    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = brd2.TransformToVisual(canvas2).Transform(new Point());

    canvas1.Children.Remove(brd2);

    brd2.Background = Brushes.Green;
    brd2.Opacity = 0.4;

    canvas2.Children.Add(brd2);

    Canvas.SetLeft(brd2, point.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(brd2, point.Y);

    ((brd2.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children[2] as RotateTransform).Angle +=
       ((canvas1.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children[2] as RotateTransform).Angle;
}
```

**Before pasting:**

[image: Start state (png).]

**After pasting:**
[image: After paste to canvas, with bad position, (png).]

Comment: Please keep the images inlined so they can be seen without the need to click on a link.

Comment: If you remove the 2 lines Canvas.SetLeft(brd2, point.X); and settop. Does that do what you're expecting? Oh. And canvas2 isn't rotated. That's what you want?

Comment: canvas1 rotated, canvas2 isn't rotated, and  border's RenderTransformOrigin isn't at center (0.5,0.5). If I delete the Canvas.SetLeft(brd2, point.X) and the settop lines the border will be at top and left corner int the canvas2. It is wrong. I want it to be the border's position the same in canvas2 after children.Add methode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to transform the border.

Here is the behind code:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double offsetx = ((brd2.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children[3] as TranslateTransform).X;
    double offsety = ((brd2.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children[3] as TranslateTransform).Y;

    Point point = brd2.TranslatePoint(new Point(brd2.RenderTransformOrigin.X * brd2.RenderSize.Width, brd2.RenderTransformOrigin.Y * brd2.RenderSize.Height), canvas2);

    canvas1.Children.Remove(brd2);

    brd2.Background = Brushes.Green;
    brd2.Opacity = 0.4;

    canvas2.Children.Add(brd2);

    Canvas.SetLeft(brd2, point.X - brd2.RenderTransformOrigin.X * brd2.RenderSize.Width - offsetx);
    Canvas.SetTop(brd2, point.Y - brd2.RenderTransformOrigin.Y * brd2.RenderSize.Height - offsety);

    ((brd2.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children[2] as RotateTransform).Angle +=
       ((canvas1.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children[2] as RotateTransform).Angle;
}
```